# How can I store the content of a pointer into a variable?

Tags: c

I was just wondering how I should go about storing the content of a pointer into a variable, particularly something along the lines of:

```
somethingpoint = getenv(somethingsomething);
```

This pointer would refer to a string .

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to declare a pointer variable, and then assign to it. You can do this all in one line of code, like this:

```
const char *value = getenv(name);
```

I'm using `const` here because `getenv` returns a pointer to a string whose contents must not be modified by the program. Using `const` lets the compiler help us honour that contract.

Answer (score 1):

```
const char* test = getenv(pointerName);
```